# Python get string right after argument switch

Tags: python, string, matching, optional-parameters

I have a script that goes using os.walk to go down a directory structure and matching files by extension and copies files to another location.

This is what i have for the file copy:

```
sourceDir=sys.argv[-2].rstrip("/")
destDir=sys.argv[-1].rstrip("/")
//copy code
```

So i would just call:

```
python mycode.py ~/a/ ~/b/
```

What i want to do is add an optional argument switch that will also match by a search pattern:

```
python mycode.py --match "pattern" ~/a/ ~/b/
```

In my code i would add this extra if:

```
if "--match" in sys.argvs:
  #try reference the string right after --match"
  for root, dir, files... etc
```

So to be precise, how can i find "pattern" if --"match" is in sys.argvs?
New to python, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your script (assuming it's a reasonably short length)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `argparse` library is great at optional argument parsing:

```
import argparse

p = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="My great script")
p.add_argument("sourceDir", type=str, help="source directory")
p.add_argument("destDir", type=str, help="destination directory")
p.add_argument("--match", type=str, dest="match", help="search pattern")

args = p.parse_args()

print args.sourceDir, args.destDir, args.match
```

That way, `args.match` will be `None` if it's not provided:

```
Davids-MacBook-Air:BarNone dgrtwo$ python mycode.py ~/a/ ~/b/
/Users/dgrtwo/a/ /Users/dgrtwo/b/ None
Davids-MacBook-Air:BarNone dgrtwo$ python mycode.py --match "pattern" ~/a/ ~/b/
/Users/dgrtwo/a/ /Users/dgrtwo/b/ pattern
```

It can also tell if there aren't the right number of arguments:

```
usage: mycode.py [-h] [--match MATCH] sourceDir destDir
mycode.py: error: too few arguments
```

And includes a help message:

```
Davids-MacBook-Air:BarNone dgrtwo$ python mycode.py -h
usage: mycode.py [-h] [--match MATCH] sourceDir destDir

My great script

positional arguments:
  sourceDir      source directory
  destDir        destination directory

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  --match MATCH  search pattern
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Lets say the --match is provided, how can i use the string patter in a loop? More precisely i am trying to do: if not pattern in file: continue.

Comment: What kind of pattern? Do you want it to be a regular expression or just allow wildcards (like `*`)? (If it's exact string matching, then your pseudocode of `if not pattern in file: continue` already works!)

Comment: It would be, for simplicity, just exact matching ( sorta like String.Contains();). I don't access to my linux machine to try it out, but what you mean by the pseudo code already works? My confusion is that i am thinking for pattern as a variable that was set somewhere, it could be anything. So basically if i ran: `python myscript.py ~/a/ ~/b/ --match "foo"`, if the string foo is not found in the filelist returned by os.walk, continue. How can i reference foo in the `if not <patterntomatch> statement`? EDIT: I think i see it, it would be `if not args.match continue:`, right?

Comment: @user1957413: It would be `if not args.match in file: continue`

Comment: Yup, that's what i thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use module OptionParser. example:

```
from optparse import OptionParser
usage = 'python test.py -m'
parse = OptionParser(usage)
parse.add_option('-m', '--match', dest='match', type='string'
                 default='', action='store',
                 help='balabala')
options, args = parse.parse_args()
```

Update: If you are using python2.7, [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html) will be better. The usage is similar as OptionParser.

Comment: `optparse` was deprecated as of 2.7, new programs should use `argparse`.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't try and parse the string yourself. Use the [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html#concepts) module instead.

Comment: Because this isn't an answer, it's a comment.

Comment: A brief answer is still an answer. This answers "how can i find "pattern" if --"match" is in sys.argvs?"